# How can I hide oneboxes in chat?

Tags: support, chat

When people are posting many images in chat, or there's a flood of questions being posted by users, I'd like to be able to ignore the oneboxes.  This then makes it easier to follow the text portion of the conversation.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to be using Firefox or Chrome.  Go install the [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/) extension.  Then create a new blank style, and copy and paste the below into it.

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("chat.stackexchange.com"), domain("chat.stackoverflow.com"), domain("chat.meta.stackoverflow.com"), domain("chat.meta.stackexchange.com") {
  .onebox { display: none !important; }
}
```

If you are using Chrome, do not paste this directly into your new style (Stylish for Chome doesn't understand `@-moz-document` and will ignore it.) Instead, click this button:

[image]

and paste the above Stylish code into the "Mozilla Format" box, and click "Overwrite Style". This will translate the Firefox script to Chrome script, and also extra the URL domains into the appropriate place.

This will hide any items in chat that have the onebox CSS class.  This means oneboxes, images, Youtube, etc.  If you want to hide a specific type of onebox, replace the 'onebox' in the middle of that code with:

- SE posts -> ob-post
- Chat quotes -> ob-message
- images -> ob-image
- Youtube -> ob-youtube

You can ignore multiple items by replacing '.onebox' with a comma-separated list of the above. Be sure to put a period before each one though (e.g. '.ob-post, .ob-message' would ignore SE posts and chat quotes).

Comment: be sure to name your Stylish script Obie-b-Gone