# How to avoid Star Wars spoilers?

Tags: support, spoilers

Over the next couple of days, most of the world will be able to finally see the new *Star Wars* film, *The Force Awakens*.  But, since it's not a global simultaneous release, some regions get to see it days ahead of other regions.

How can I use Scifi.SE over the next few days and avoid spoilers?

Comment: Stay off the site until you've seen the movie? (Yeah, okay, that's not using the site, but it will ensure you don't get spoilers from it. Other web sites may not be as well mannered.)

Comment: And avoid meta too since people now insist on asking questions about their star wars questions...

Comment: I avoided all social media until I got to see TFA last night. I'm actually annoyed by the aggressive anti-spoilers. Because of this, I ended up asking a dupe since search results don't come up as easily, or aren't evident of what they are asking.

Comment: You could try keeping your eyes closed while using the site.... just a suggestion....

Comment: Avoid the Internet in general

Comment: I think there was a Chrome add-on or something that hides all content that registers as Star Wars spoiler-y.

Comment: I read two spoilers before watching the movie: one stealth spoiler as a random comment on a random non-star wars related youtube video and one while browsing stackoverflow and noticing a title in the "hot network questions" section. Conclusion: you can't...

Comment: Doesn't do anything if the questions is in the 'Hot Questions' list (I've seen two fairly spoily questions in the past two days). I'm sure it would be appreciated if moderators would rename spoiler titles or perhaps prod the askers to do so.

Comment: @labyrinth related question about the aggressive anti-spoilers: [Will we ever clean up those ridiculous spoiler-free “The Force Awakens” question titles?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/will-we-ever-clean-up-those-ridiculous-spoiler-free-the-force-awakens-question)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

1. Ignore the tags [the-force-awakens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-force-awakens) and [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars), and [set ignored tags to be hidden](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12522/102999). Also avoid the review queues (and flag queues, if you're a mod), as those ignore your ignored tags setting. Note: This does not work in the SE app.
2. If you use chat, [ignore the feed bots](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#mute)
3. If you use chat, you can also [hide all oneboxes](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7706/how-can-i-hide-oneboxes-in-chat), so as to avoid spoilers from other users posting questions into chat.
4. Use [Adblock](https://getadblock.com/) or [some CSS](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6858/1027) to hide the Hot Network Questions.

Comment: These are not the [easy single click] answers we were looking for,  

no matter how correct. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Is this the highest-voted post there's ever been on SFF meta? :-o

Answer (score 14):

A Chrome extension, there is. [Force Block](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-block-the-star-wars/bplpphlobgcnjhoglonpnkooaaenlmol), preemptively all Force Awakens Spoilers, it blocks.

Description:

> Block pages containing spoilers from Star Wars: The Force Awakens, with smart pattern detection and a whitelist for false alarms.

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest you avoid all SE sites as it seems TFA questions asked here are being promoted to the 'hot network questions' list. While you can only see the title, they often give away enough information in themselves.

eg. just from reading Programmers, I now know that:

> Luke goes to some Jedi Temple.
>  He leaves a map showing to find him.
>  there There is a star killer base.
>  Han flies through the shields of said base.

Comment: Per my answer's #4, there are 2 methods to hide the HNQ.

Comment: But I bet you don't know that *?!!@ kills #@& (redacted because I'm feeling kind) ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor I just love it when one profanity kills another profanity. lol